# My system always crashes while booting [related to Nvidia driver]

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, google-chrome

As I mentioned in Q, I am facing a problem while booting. Previously I used elementary without problem, but recently I changed to Ubuntu 14.04, I am facing these issues like:

1. Background crash (i can't get exact screenshot, but that is similar to this [image](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=828479))
2. Browsers crashes (firefox and google-chrome newest version)

Sometime i get : loop login infinitive
My computer detail:
[image]
My graphic driver is : Nvidia 352.55.
Please let me know, if I have to produce more information.
**The proble resolves after several reboots.**
After

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
sudo reboot
```

My system becomes like:
[image]
Can't open Dash, Launcher, Shortcut like `Alt + Ctrl + T` .
Lucky i have Folder at my desktop so i can open via `Mouse click`.
After fix Ubuntu lost Dash, Launcher, Shortcut
Browsers still crashing
Browsers still crashing :D

```
~$ google-chrome
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h: 492: elf_machine_rela_relative: Assertion `((reloc->r_info) & 0xffffffff) == 8' failed!
~$ firefox
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**The proble resolves after several reboots.**

Comment: Have you ran - sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade What are the errors, if any?

Comment: Just curious - which OS did you install ? The background image reminds me as of being from debian 7. :)

Comment: Oh i just changed my background image haha. Ubuntu 14.04.3LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the latest official NVIDIA drivers 355 - NVIDIA improved the drivers and fixed many issues !

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and password.

Uninstall NVIDIA drivers 352 - execute these commands :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and password.

Install NVIDIA drivers 355 - execute these commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
sudo reboot
```

Comment: updated Q after follwed your answer

Comment: @BeGood : Please try the following ... open a terminal and execute these commands (one after the other): sudo apt-get update |
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop |
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity !

Comment: hmm still have same errors

Comment: [Same problem and Same fix here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) Thanks cl-netbox

Comment: Updated Q @cl-netbox

Comment: Still getting loop login infinitive :D