# Black screen after 15.10 upgrade, not even getting into tty1 anymore

Tags: boot, gnome, upgrade, kubuntu, lightdm

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 and upgraded to 15.10 tonight. After restarting I'm getting a black screen with a flickering message from my window manager.

First I was able to get into tty1, so I reinstalled some drivers (I'm using Intel and nvidia with prime, although since the update I can't even switch to nvidia anymore), the gnome desktop, lightdm and xserver. Nothing helped and I still only got a black screen or the low graphics mode warning.

Then I added the xorg-edgers after reading an answer here, which screwed me over completely: now I can't even open the terminal because lightdm keeps restarting! I can't get into the grub menu either for some reason although I'm holding down shift while booting.

Edit: Maybe I explained my problem poorly. When the system boots I get a black screen and the same message (either "fsck from util-linux 2.26.2" or "started light display manager") over and over again while the screen " restarts ". I can't get into the grub menu by holding shift during boot and I can't even get into tty1 with alt ctrl f1, because I always get thrown out of it by said message. So right now I can do literally nothing because I don't even get the opportunity to run any commands

I don't see how the suggested related question has anything to do with mine whatsoever

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My system always crashes while booting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/696657/my-system-always-crashes-while-booting)

Answer (score 1):

Completely reinstall the NVIDIA drivers! I assume that you have a GPU newer than GEFORCE 400.

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and password. Now uninstall every NVIDIA related software by executing:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and password. Now reinstall the NVIDIA drivers by executing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Note:

As you did not provide any information about your NVIDIA graphics card check [drivers versions](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us).
Replace 355 with the latest stable main version number supporting your NVIDIA GEFORCE GPU.
If you ever have had bumblebee installed before to switch between graphics - also remove this.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds :  Maybe you can call it a duplicate, but then all answers and question questions regarding this topic are duplicates - important is : This answers addresses the problem ! :)

Comment: @edwardtorvalds : Shall we now mark everything as duplicate, or isn't it betterand more helpful for a (new) user to just answer the question ?

Comment: marking duplicate also helps (new) user. after all they want answer and your previous answers are exactly the same as this

Comment: please take a look at this: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14692/294611

Comment: Maybe I explained my problem poorly. When the system boots I get a black screen and the same message (either "fsck from util-linux 2.26.2" or "started light display manager") over and over again while the screen " restarts ". I can't get into the grub menu by holding shift during boot and I can't even get into tty1 with alt shift f1, because I always get thrown out of it by said message. So right now I can do literally nothing because I don't even get the opportunity to run any commands

Comment: @Max : Maybe something went completely wrong while performing the upgrade (think of kernel upgrade to version 4.2) ... I suggest that you perform a complete new (clean) fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10 and after this install the NVIDIA drivers following the instructions given in the answer. As it is a clean install you can skip part 1 (removal) and start with part 2 (install) - I recommend to reformat the ubuntu system partition with ext4 using GParted before - the tool is included in the ubuntu install media. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox : That's what I ended up having to do.  Of course it's very disappointing that I can't even do a simple OS upgrade on Ubuntu without the risk of completely destroying my system but oh well... Anyway, thank you for the help.