# Black screen after installing graphic drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 15.10

I just installed the nvidia drivers for my gpu following this [guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1916961). After the reboot i quickly see tty1 login but then the screen goes black with a flashing underscore (_) and I can't do anything.

Im running Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Did you install from homepage nvidia or via terminal?

Comment: I installed it from the terminal

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/696662/413306 hope this help you

Comment: for future reference, you can install the nvidia drivers through apt-get, there really is no reason to install from source, especially on 15.10

Answer (score 0):

I did this night before last with 15.04.
I followed these instructions: http://www.allaboutlinux.eu/remove-nouveau-and-install-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-15-04/

Specifically notice the bit about the extra build packages and disabling the nouveau driver.

To recover from where you are you can:
1) boot into recovery root shell and `mount -o remount,rw /` to be able to make changes.
 
2) Then do a `NVIDIA-Linux-xxx-xxx.xx.run --uninstall` and reboot which should get you back to a workable state.

Comment: the OP did not use apt-get but installed from source instead so this will not work

Comment: Thanks I have updated my answer to show how to unisntall from the package that you get from nvidia. I was coming from the propritary flgrx driver so it was apt-get remove for my case from two nights ago.

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove a particular X11 config file. This file is not really required.

```
rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe
```

Somehow, the existence of the above X11 configuration file causes the OS to throw that error.

2.Restart lightdm GUI server.

```
service lightdm restart
```

This will restart the lightdm GUI server and voila your desktop is back!