# Nvidia driver can't run with the newest Kernel

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3LTS, I just updated my Kernel to 4.2.0-21 via tty1 but my PC didn't show login screen.I tried :

- Reinstall Nvidia driver 358 (PPA) but it didn't work with new kernel
- Reinstall Nvidia driver 358 (PPA) with old kernel ( 4.2.0-19-generic ) and it's working ok.

How can I fix the problem with new Kernel?

#### *If I can provide more information, please don't hesitate let me know!*

Comment: Nvidia-358 is a beta driver and is not supported.

Comment: So I should install 355 version instead of 358 right? @Pilot6

Comment: The supported stable version is 352.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install supported Nvidia drivers from the official Ubuntu repository by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia.*'
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Comment: Still not work with new Kernel. And have some problem with old kernel like loop login, doens't show login screen.

Comment: It does work with this kernel. But you need to disable the PPA you install the drivers from too.

Comment: So i need to disable PPA and reinstall nvidia-352 right?

Comment: Maybe your solution conflicts with my old question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/696657/my-system-always-crashes-while-booting-related-to-nvidia-driver)

Comment: @BeGood : Although I think that this does not solve the problem, here are the commands to completely remove the PPA : sudo apt-get install ppa-purge | sudo ppa-purge ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa ... I assume that it has got more something to do with the fact that kernel 4.2 is not officially supported in Ubuntu 14.04. The latest officially supported version is 3.19 (Ubuntu 14.04.3) - so you have 2 options : Either use the (in your case) working version 4.2.0-19 until the next (maybe working) version is available or revert back the system to the officially supported kernel 3.19. :)